# Azure: Include unreferenced DLLs when publish

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

I was struggling to publish my project because some DLLs were missing. After some investigations, I found what I was looking for:

http://sedodream.com/2010/05/01/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployBuildPackageIncludingExtraFilesOrExcludingSpecificFiles.aspx

Here my code:

```
  <Target Name="CustomCollectFiles">
    <Message Text="Publishing unreferenced DLLs" Importance="High" />
    <ItemGroup>
      <_CustomFiles Include="$(UnreferencedDlls)" />
      <FilesForPackagingFromProject Include="%(_CustomFiles.Identity)">
        <DestinationRelativePath>bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
      </FilesForPackagingFromProject>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

It is working fine now but only when I publish on local. When I try to publish on Azure, these same DLLs are missing. So I tried to add the following line:

```
<DestinationRelativePath>obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp\bin\%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)</DestinationRelativePath>
```

Because when I publish on azure, the Output says:

> Copying all files to temporary location below for package/publish:
>   obj\Release\Package\PackageTmp.

But still, the DLLs are missing and I have no idea how to add them when I'm publishing on Azure.

Comment: Have you inject your custom target into `CopyAllFilesToSingleFolder` by following code: `<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn> ...` ? Check the detailed info from:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-extra-files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find a solution. The first one add the DLLs when I deploy on my local machine and the second do the same thing but when I deploy the app on Azure.

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Publish on the FILE SYSTEM -->
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForPackageDependsOn>

    <!-- Publish on AZURE: Web Deploy -->
    <CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMSDeployDependsOn>
      CustomCollectFiles;
      $(CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMSDeployDependsOn);
    </CopyAllFilesToSingleFolderForMSDeployDependsOn>
  </PropertyGroup>
```